# Redis connetion reset periodically

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I am a student and English is not my first language, so my description may be confusing. Please forgive my poor English.

I met a problem with Redis in my Spring Boot project. It can work well when I just start my project, but it will throw a exception that Connection Reset after I have left it about 6 minutes. However, when it throw the exception and I try it again immediately, it can work well again. But the same problem will happen again if I don't use it for about 6 minutes.

The exceptions are like following.

```
2024-02-22 11:49:05,174 ERROR [communityScheduler_Worker-2] o.q.c.JobRunShell [JobRunShell.java:211] Job communityJobGroup.postScoreRefreshJob threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Redis exception
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:38)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.await(LettuceConnection.java:969)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.lambda$doInvoke$4(LettuceConnection.java:826)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker$Synchronizer.invoke(LettuceInvoker.java:665)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceInvoker.just(LettuceInvoker.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceSetCommands.sCard(LettuceSetCommands.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.sCard(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:824)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.sCard(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:755)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultSetOperations.lambda$size$17(DefaultSetOperations.java:264)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultSetOperations.size(DefaultSetOperations.java:264)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.BoundOperationsProxyFactory$BoundOperationsMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(BoundOperationsProxyFactory.java:177)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.BoundOperationsProxyFactory$BoundOperationsMethodInterceptor.invoke(BoundOperationsProxyFactory.java:148)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy121.size(Unknown Source)
    at com.nowcoder.community.quartz.PostScoreRefreshJob.execute(PostScoreRefreshJob.java:63)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.Exceptions.bubble(Exceptions.java:83)
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.Futures.awaitOrCancel(Futures.java:250)
    at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.await(LettuceConnection.java:967)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:254)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
```

My Redis version is 7.0.12, and it is run in the docker container. My project is used Spring boot 3.1.5, and I use matching spring-boot-starter-data-redis to operate Redis. My JDK version is 17. My application.properties about Redis is like following.

```bash
spring.data.redis.host=${community.spring.data.redis.host}
spring.data.redis.port=${community.spring.data.redis.port}
spring.data.redis.password=${community.spring.data.redis.password}
spring.data.redis.database=${community.spring.data.redis.database}

spring.data.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active=15
spring.data.redis.lettuce.pool.max-idle=15
spring.data.redis.lettuce.pool.min-idle=15
spring.data.redis.lettuce.pool.max-wait=10000
```

I run my Redis on the remote server by the following script.

```bash
docker run --restart=always -p 6379:6379 \
-v ./data:/data --name redis \
--network community --network-alias redis -d \
redis:7.0.12  --requirepass
```

My solution for this problem is to create a scheduled task to operate the Redis per 1min. Of course, this is not a good way because it will waste the network resources.

I want to know why it threw the exception and how I can solve it without the scheduled task. Thank you for your help.